# mat-autocomplete (optionSelected) is not being fired on ios, its working fine on android and browser

Tags: angular, cordova, autocomplete, angular-material

Mat autocomplete is not behaving as expected on ios in a cordova app as `optionSelected` is not triggering and i am not able to select and value.

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="getValueSelected()">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option[filterKey]">
                {{option[filterKey]}}
            </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

And it's working good on android and browser. Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: What versions of iOS, Angular and cordova are you using?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I am having the same problem on IOS device.